# Android SDK - Could not find 'adb'

Tags: centos7, android-sdk-tools, webdriver-io, appium-android

I'm trying to use Android SDK in Centos 7 for an Appium suite using webdriverio.  I am getting the following error when I try to run my suite, it is having trouble finding `adb` for some reason:

```
ERROR: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find 'adb' in ["/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb","/opt/android-sdk/emulator/adb","/opt/android-sdk/tools/adb","/opt/android-sdk/tools/bin/adb"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at '/opt/android-sdk'?
```

Running `which adb` shows it in `/usr/bin/adb`.  Do you know how to install Android Build Tools at `/opt/android-sdk`?  Or what I should be doing in this situation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but by reading the error i can say that please check that your adb divers are properly installed in that folder where u have installed your software